Two questions about "America the Beautiful"
suorce: "America the Beautiful"
1

O beautiful for pilgrim feet
Whose stern impassioned stress
A thoroughfare for freedom beat
Across the wilderness.

I can't understand the whose-clause (i.e. "whose ... wilderness").
2

O beautiful for heroes proved
In liberating strife,
Who more than self their country loved,
And mercy more than life

In my opinion, "Who more than self their country loved" = who loved their country more than self; but what's "mercy more than life" ?

As to (1), what’s your question? For (2), your opinion is correct, and the “mercy more than life” bit means that they loved being merciful to others more than they loved their own lives.

According to the wilderness verse, the pilgrims spread freedom west (away from England, yes, for the indigenous, no.) The word order is twisted for rhythm and rhyme ... if you consider wilderness to rhyme with stress, which it doesn't. Untangled: Pilgrim feet beat a thoroughfare for freedom across the wilderness, due to their stern impassioned marching sound (accented stress of their feet).

There, stress refers to the pressure or impact of their feet against the earth. They made a trail across the wilderness by following the same route in their thousands.  pilgrim feet is the noun-phrase to which whose refers.

(1) The pilgrim’s feet “beat a thoroughfare for freedom across the wilderness” - the settlers forged a path across the land with the goal of freedom.
Your interpretation of (2) is correct.
